# How to monitor JDBC calls and statistics with Grafana

Tags: jdbc, grafana, prometheus

**How can I monitor JDBC calls(Oracle/MySql/PostgreSQL etc.) statistics for my spring boot application with Grafana/Prometheus?.**

- Do we have any plugin for it ?.
- is it possible to capture this statistics through Grafana/Prometheus?

Specifically I am looking for statistics like, i.e.

- How many open connection I have with database?
- Whether my database is up or not?
- What queries are causing longest response time etc ?.

Answer (score 4):

You can try using [micrometer](https://micrometer.io/docs). This is the metrics provider for spring boot. I'm currently working on the same thing, and I'm not completely aware of all the way one can use micrometer. So, hopefully the below information will be useful for you.

There are ways to expose spring boot application endpoints to prometheus, and then you can link up grafana to use prometheus. Checkout this [link](https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-actuator-metrics-monitoring-dashboard-prometheus-grafana/) for an example on how you can do it

By default, micrometer will include the JvmMemoryMetrics, UptimeMetrics, etc,. But you can use the *binders provided in the below package* in your application by adding it as a bean.

```
io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder
```

For example (code written in Kotlin),

```
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.db.PostgreSQLDatabaseMetrics
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.jvm.ClassLoaderMetrics
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import javax.sql.DataSource

/**
 * Class to configure binders for micrometer metrics for this application
 */
@Configuration
open class MetricsConfiguration(private val dataSource: DataSource) {

    @Bean
    open fun jvmMemoryMetrics(): ClassLoaderMetrics {
        return ClassLoaderMetrics()
    }

    @Bean
    open fun dbMetrics(): PostgreSQLDatabaseMetrics {
        return  PostgreSQLDatabaseMetrics(dataSource, "database-name")
    }

}
```

You can also write custom binders & metrics if needed. Refer to the [micrometer docs](https://micrometer.io/docs) for more information on those.

Comment: Thanks Abishek. I have tried exploring Micrometer, but it really didn't fit my requirement. I am looking for solution which is less invasive(to native application) and preferable it needs only config change and not code change. Do we have any other tools you know of which fits this requirement ?.

Answer (score 0):

Exporters help in exposing the metrics of the hosts to the endpoint.
The endpoints can either be `/metrics` or `/prometheus`

You would need to configure your `prometheus.yml` to scrape the metrics from the endpoints

Prometheus official documentation has a list of exporters

https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/exporters/

You can find exporters for Oracle,MySql and PostGresSQL and a generic JDBC exporter.

You would need to install this exporter on your database machine to obtain DB specific metrics.

For spring boot application related metrics like "Number of queries to the database", you can write custom metrics using Micrometer for spring boot 2.x

Comment: Hi Sania, your answer is correct from standpoint of database metric collection. Our requirement was to have prometheus metrics collected from application side(because multiple application can connect to same database) to fetch respective application's following jdbc statistics,  - numConnectionsDefaultUser,
numBusyConnectionsAllUsers,
numConnectionsAllUsers,
threadPoolSize,
maxPoolSize,
numBusyConnections,
numConnections etc....